# jQuery UI Themeroller Question

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I just created a custom theme at http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ and downloaded the theme.

Now how do I get started and implement the CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Have a read through the [jQuery UI Theming API](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/API)**

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of themeroller is to theme jQuery UI widgets.  You can use the theme within your own site and for your own widgets, but you'll need to open up the files and look at the classes so you can apply them within your HTML.